# How to hide packages (but still use them) in python setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I've been struggling to find a way to hide subpackages in python setuptools whilst still using them in the top level `__init__.py` script.

Say I have this file structure:

```
/root
    setup.py
    main_package/
        __init__.py
        subpackage_to_hide/
            __init__.py
            hidden_script.py
```

And `hidden_script.py` contains a simple function:

```
def hidden_func():
    print("I am hidden")
```

Which `main_package/__init__.py` accesses:

```
from .subpackage_to_hide.hidden_script import hidden_func
```

Now, say I deploy this pip package, download it to a separate virtual environment and create a new project. When I `import main_package as mp` in my new python script, I want to be able to call `mp.hidden_func()`, whilst at the same time I shouldn't be able to `import main_package.subpackage_to_hide.hidden_script as hs`. Is this possible?

I've tried to do an exclude:

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    name="main_package",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["main_package.subpackage_to_hide"]),
    ...
)
```

But this excludes the subpackage from the build and thus creates errors for the `import` statement in `main_package/__init__.py`. I still want the function to be available here, but as mentioned I don't want `import main_package.subpackage_to_hide.hidden_script as hs` to work - I want this to be a private module that can only be made available through the `main_package/__init__.py` script.

Comment: It's impossible to do what you want. Python is very open and reflective language. Almost nothing could be hidden, everything is available for a user to read and import. The only thing that can be hidden from reading is code written in C and compiled, but even it can be imported and its objects investigated using very powerful Python reflection APIs starting with simple `dir()`.

Comment: @phd Alright, that was my fear. Thanks!